# Laravel font defined by locale

Tags: php, laravel, fonts

How can I define `font-family` for my app based on user locale?

Let say user switch to `ID` then I change font-family of my site body.

`app.scss`

As of sample I've added 3 fonts and try to use each of them based on selected locale

```
//use for "en"
@font-face {
  font-family: Nunito;
  src: url('/fonts/Nunito/Nunito-Regular.ttf');
}
//use for "id"
@font-face {
  font-family: Righteous;
  src: url('/fonts/Righteous/Righteous-Regular.ttf');
}
// use for "fa"
@font-face {
  font-family: Dirooz;
  src: url('/fonts/dirooz/Dirooz.ttf');
}
```

**any idea?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it from within the Vue component triggering another method when the user selects a locale

Assume that you have @font-face defined in your css for all three

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Nunito;
  src: url('/fonts/Nunito/Nunito-Regular.ttf');
}
//use for "id"
@font-face {
  font-family: Righteous;
  src: url('/fonts/Righteous/Righteous-Regular.ttf');
}
// use for "fa"
@font-face {
  font-family: Dirooz;
  src: url('/fonts/dirooz/Dirooz.ttf');
}
```

Then in the Vue component

```js
setFontFamily() {    
    let styleTags = document.querySelectorAll('style');
    if(this.initialStyleTagsCount < styleTags.length) {
        //Remove the previous style tag
        let lastStyle = styleTags[styleTags.length - 1];
        document.head.removeChild(lastStyle);
    }

    let style = document.createElement('style');
    //style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`
    //    @font-face {
    //        font-family: ${this.fontFamily};
    //        src: url('${this.fontFamilyUrl}`);
    //    }`
    //));

    style.appendChild(
        document.createTextNode(`body { font-family: '${this.fontFamily}' }`)
    );

    document.head.appendChild(style);    
}
```

You can have a lookup table for values of fontFamily and fontFamily url corresponding to the available locales within the component and probably computed properties for fontFamily & fontFamily url based on selected locale

```js
data(){
    return {
        //fonts: {
        //    en: 'Nunito', url: '/fonts/Nunito/Nunito-Regular.ttf'},
        //    id: { fontFamily: 'Righteous', url: '/fonts/Righteous/Righteous-Regular.tt'},
        //    fa: { fontFamily: 'Dirooz', url: '/fonts/dirooz/Dirooz.ttf'}
       // },

        fonts: {
            en: 'Nunito',
            id: 'Righteous',
            fa: 'Dirooz'
        },
        initialStyleTagsCount: this.getStyleTagsCount()
        // other data properties
    }
},

computed:{

    //fontFamily() {
    //    return this.fonts[this.locale]['fontFamily'];
    //},
    //fontFamilyUrl() {
    //    return this.fonts[this.locale]['url'];
    //},
    
    fontFamily() {
        return this.fonts[this.locale];
    }
},

methods:{
    getStyleTagsCount() {
        return document.querySelectorAll('style').length;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've placed your code in dropdown component but it doesn't change the font

Comment: I also used it with `i18n` like this `this.fonts[this.$i18n.locale]["fontFamily"]`

Comment: Have you applied @font-face via css to body anywhere in your css? Or something like body{ font-family: 'Nunito'} in the css

Comment: just in `_variables.scss` as laravel default

Comment: @mafortis Have updated the answer. I guess also need to set the font-family on body for the fonts to change - have a look , try and let me know

Comment: quick question, does it supposed to add inline style to my html or make changes in app.css? because in console i cannot see any changes being happen.

Comment: @mafortis Sorry there was a typo - extra colon after body, removed & updated in the answer. This will add a new `<style>` tag at the end within the `<head>` of the page. And I guess if you have the @font-face definitions in your css then those can be omitted from the js and the lookup table can then be just the font-family

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work, and i think your code should be changed like this https://ibb.co/Tg24h1y because if I copy paste your code there are several errors.

Comment: Ok i got it to be printed at the bottom of head tag but we have tiny issue.

Comment: What tiny issue?

Comment: Each time I change the lang it adds new style tag without removing the old one. I think we need to remove old style tag before adding new one

Comment: Ahh yes, but then need an empty `<style>` tag at the end of head tag so that when the method runs for the first time it removes this empty tag

Comment: or we can just check if there is any previous style tag instead of adding empty one. maybe?

Comment: let say make style counter in component to check existence of previous style tag?

Comment: Can do that if you are sure that there's no other style tag

Comment: check this out and let me know what you think https://ibb.co/GQJP7Sh

Comment: this is just about knowing that we have previous style added or not, how to actually remove it from html that i need your help :D

Comment: @mafortis Have updated answer to get the initial count of style tags on the page, when it loads and then if there are more than the initial count then we remove the last one